# Tikz Grid goes beyond graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-euclide

The Grid goes beyond the graph, as you can see in the screenshot below.
What do i have to change, to make the grid align with the graph? It should only be inside the coordinate system.

```
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymax=6, xmin=-6, ymin=-1]
\tkzGrid[xmax=6, ymax=6]
%\tkzAxeXY
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=x, 
    ylabel={y}, % max(0, x)
    legend pos=north west,
    legend cell align=left
]
\addplot[color=blue]{max(0, x)};
\addplot[color=red]{1/(1+exp(-x))};
\addplot[color=green]{(exp(x)-exp(-x))/(exp(x)+exp(-x))};
\addlegendentry{ReLu(x)}
\addlegendentry{sigmoid(x)}
\addlegendentry{tanh(x)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Relu und sigmoid function}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are mixing two packages. pgfplots works on its own and also uses its own coordinates system, so it's better to use this package's options:   

- Remove the `\tkzInit` and `\tkzGrid` commands   

- To add a grid in the axis environment, just add the option `grid`. If you want to change the axis limits, you can add the options 'xmin=...` in the axis environment. You can read [the documentation](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=x, 
    ylabel=y,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend cell align=left,
    grid,
    ytick distance=1,
]
\addplot[blue] {max(0, x)};
\addplot[red] {1/(1+exp(-x))};
\addplot[green] {(exp(x)-exp(-x))/(exp(x)+exp(-x))};
\addlegendentry{ReLu(x)}
\addlegendentry{sigmoid(x)}
\addlegendentry{tanh(x)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with grid lines]